# selecting all or some parent / child checkboxes in a styled format

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

First of all: http://jsfiddle.net/1q5st19f/

I have a checkbox group where if all the child checkboxes (countries) are checked, the parent checkbox (region) becomes checked as well. Likewise, if the parent checkbox is unchecked, the child checkboxes should be unchecked, too. I found a script that worked perfectly until I styled the checkboxes with prettyCheckable (from http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/).

If I remove prettyCheckable, it works. If I add it, it's correctly styled but won't work anymore. What am I doing wrong? I tried to rename the classes but that didn't work either.

The basic markup is like

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Africa 
    <div class="content">   
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="cntrs[]" class="childCheckBox" data-label=""> Algeria<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="cntrs[]" class="childCheckBox" data-label=""> Angola<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="cntrs[]" class="childCheckBox" data-label=""> Benin<br />
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Looking at this page, http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/ ... I see that this class has a method to explicitly check or uncheck the checkbox.  It may be that this class doesn't use the "checked" attribute to toggle its checked status?

Comment: That makes sense ...but I don't know enough about jQuery to know if that means it's not possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

prettyCheckable made this a bit tricky. It says in the documentation that you can use `$('#myInput').prettyCheckable('check');` but I could not get it to work. So I just used the anchors class `checked` instead to determine if the checkbox is checked.

This may not be the most pretty implementation but it's working. You should make the code more modular an maybe reconsider some of the choices I quickly made.

First I removed the `childCheckBox` from the HTML and initialized prettyCheckable with options, so I could get the class to the wrapper div:

```
// make childCheckboxes prettyCheckable
$('.content input:checkbox').each(function () {
    $(this).prettyCheckable({
        // add this class to the wrapper div created by prettyCheckable
        customClass: "childCheckBox"
    });
});
```

Same with the parentCheckbox:

```
// make parentCheckBox prettyCheckable
$('input:checkbox.parentInput').prettyCheckable({
    // add this class to the wrapper div created by prettyCheckable
    customClass: "parentCheckBox"
});
```

I also changed childCheckBox click event to do the functionality you wanted

```
//clicking the last unchecked or checked checkbox should check or uncheck the parent checkbox
    $('.childCheckBox').click(function () {
        var $parentAnchor = $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.parentCheckBox a');
        var $childAnchors = $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find('.childCheckBox a');
        var $thisAnchor = $(this).find('a');

        var parentIsChecked = $parentAnchor.hasClass('checked');
        var thisIsChecked = $thisAnchor.hasClass('checked');

        var isLastOne = true;
        // loop through all childCheckBoxes and determine if this is the last one checked or unchecked
        $childAnchors.each(function (index) {
            if ((!thisIsChecked && $(this).hasClass('checked'))
                || (thisIsChecked && !$(this).hasClass('checked'))) {
                isLastOne = false;
            }
        });

        // if the childCheckBox was the last one, change the state of the parentCheckBox
        if (isLastOne && thisIsChecked) {
            $parentAnchor.addClass('checked');
        } else if (isLastOne && !thisIsChecked) {
            $parentAnchor.removeClass('checked');
        }
    });
```

I was pretty tired when forking this, so I hope I didn't do any stupid mistakes. If you have any questions about the code, please ask.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1q5st19f/17/

Answer (score 0):

This took me forever to debug.  There were a number of issues most importantly of which was that you are using a very backlevel version of prettyCheckable.  However, after changing to the latest level and starting again, I have a fully working solution for you.  See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1q5st19f/18/).

I started again from the beginning but here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="group">
        <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" data-label="Africa"/>
        <div class="content">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="childCheckBox" data-label="Algeria" />
            <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" class="childCheckBox" data-label="Angola" />
            <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" class="childCheckBox" data-label="Benin" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
        $(this).prettyCheckable();
    });

    $(".parentCheckBox").change(function (e) {
        var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
        $(".childCheckBox", $(this).closest(".group")).each(function (i, e) {
            $(e).prettyCheckable(checked?"check":"uncheck");
        });
    });

    $(".childCheckBox").change(function(e) {
        var checkedCount = unCheckedCount = 0;
        $(e.currentTarget).closest(".content").find(".childCheckBox").each(function(i,e2) {
            if ($(e2).prop("checked")) {
                checkedCount++;
            } else {
                unCheckedCount++;
            }
        });
        if (unCheckedCount == 0) {
            $(e.currentTarget).closest(".group").find(".parentCheckBox").prettyCheckable("check");
        } else {
            $(e.currentTarget).closest(".group").find(".parentCheckBox").prettyCheckable("uncheck");
        }
    });
});
```

I'll be delighted to answer any questions you may have.

The semantics of checking or unchecking all children could have an alternate solution shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/opL285h3/4/).  It talks to when the parent checkbox should be checked or unchecked as a function of the children.

Answer (score 0):

What prettyCheckable does behind the scenes, is it hides the checkboxes and adds an `a` tag to the page, and updates the hidden checkboxes when the `a` tag is clicked. The `a` tag also gets a style of `checked` when the checkbox is checked. There appears to be a bug though, that the `checked` class is not added to or removed from the `a` tag when the state of the checkboxes is manipulated through code. Anyway, your JavaScript was correctly updating the state of the checkboxes, but prettyCheckable wasn't detecting that and failed to update its classes.

Anyway, I rewrote your script so all the logic is handled in 1 event handler, and I included a work-around for the prettyCheckable bug, but I left your HTML alone so you should only have to replace your JavaScript code.  See below for a runnable example:

```js
$('input:checkbox').prettyCheckable();

$("input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var parent = checkbox.closest("fieldset");
  if (checkbox.hasClass("parentCheckBox")) {
    //this is a parent, check or uncheck all children
    var isChecked = checkbox.is(":checked");
 
    //add checked attribute in the DOM and add the class for prettyCheckable on all children
    parent.find("input.childCheckBox:checkbox").prop("checked", isChecked).each(function() {
      if (isChecked)
        $(this).next("a").addClass('checked');
      else
        $(this).next("a").removeClass('checked');
    });
  } else {
    //this is a child, check or uncheck the parent
    var parentCheckbox = parent.find("input.parentCheckBox:checkbox");
    var isChecked = !parent.find("input.childCheckBox:checkbox").get().some(function(item) {
      return !$(item).is(":checked");
    });
    
    //add the checked attribute to the dom and add the class for prettyCheckable
    parentCheckbox.prop("checked", isChecked);
    if (isChecked)
      parentCheckbox.next("a").addClass('checked');
    else
      parentCheckbox.next("a").removeClass('checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://qfuse.com/js/utils/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.js"></script>
<link href="http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/js/prettyCheckable/dist/prettyCheckable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<fieldset>
 <input type="checkbox" class="parentCheckBox" /> Africa 
 <div class="content"> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="cntrs[]" class="childCheckBox" data-label="" /> Algeria<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="cntrs[]" class="childCheckBox" data-label="" /> Angola<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="cntrs[]" class="childCheckBox" data-label="" /> Benin<br />
</div>
</fieldset>
```